# How to add a jnilib in classpath using Netbeans 6.6?

Tags: java, netbeans

How to add a jnilib file in classpath using Netbeans 6.8?

Answer (score 2):

Add `-Djava.library.path="lib/libname.jnilib"` to project properties -> run -> VM_Options.

This works for Netbeans 6.9